# Where is the macro CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION defined in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macros, build-settings

This post [How to set CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION in xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673280/how-to-set-current-project-version-in-xcode-8) says that setting is defined in the Build Settings, but how would I tell the name of the macro, such as CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION from the Build Settings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With **Xcode 10.3** or bellow, the version and build numbers of the App were defined in the `info.plist` file as "**Bundle version string, short**" and "**Bundle version**" (key names if opened as Source Code are `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion`). With the proper setting, multiple targets would share the `info.plist` file and you could change the version/build for all targets in one single place

With **Xcode 11.1**, each target defines the version/build numbers individually in the target Build Settings under "**Marketing Version**" and "**Current Project Version**" in the **Versioning** section

The settings in the plist file are now pointing to the Build Settings with `$(MARKETING_VERSION)` and `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`

**So, as a summary:**

**- App version**

Found in the `info.plist` as "**Bundle version string, short**" ("**CFBundleShortVersionString**" in the XML), that points with "**$(MARKETING_VERSION)**" to the Build Settings field named "**Marketing Version**".

**-App build number**

This is found  in the `info.plist` as "**Bundle version**" ("**CFBundleVersion**" in the XML), that points with "**$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)**" to the Build Settings field named "**Current Project Version**".

[image]
The nice naming consistency is courtesy of Apple