# Xcode 13.3 Apple Watch app targets ((null)) CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

Since updating to Xcode 13.3 (13E113), out WatchKit target fails to build in the ValidateEmbeddedBinary step with the error message:

> error: The value of CFBundleShortVersionString in your WatchKit app’s
> Info.plist (X.Y.Z) does not match the value in your companion app’s
> Info.plist ((null)). These values are required to match.

All info.plists look perfectly fine! This is only happening in XCode 13.3.

The Release Note of 13.3 mentions this bug as fixed: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_3-release-notes ‍♂️

Any one has come across this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone coming across this in Xcode 13.3 (13E113): Apparently starting this version one must use the `MARKETING_VERSION` and `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` build settings in the companion app target, and avoid using `CFBundleShortVersionString` directly inside your Info.plist for that purpose. Doing this solved the problem on our side.

Thanks to Apple FB Engineers for swift response.

Comment: Thanks for this! More details on how to use those settings in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425634/where-is-the-macro-current-project-version-defined-in-xcode).